# Why is my Java linked drop out stack not working?

Tags: java

I am implementing a drop out stack using links in Java, but the last element is not dropping.

If the stack size is n, the bottom element should be lost when the n+1 element is pushed onto the top.

The last element (1) is being set to null, as I can see with the debugger, but not being removed from the stack (it is still printing).

Whats wrong?

````
       /**
        * DropOutStack represents a drop out stack 
        * implementation using linked lists.
        */
       public class DropOutStack<T>
    {
        private int count; //counter var
        private LinearNode<T> top; //var for top of stack
        private int stackSize; //var for size of stack
    
       /**
        * Constructor for DropOutStack class. Sets the size        
        * of stack initially. 
        * @param stackSize
        */
        public DropOutStack(int stackSize) 
        {
            count=0; //set count to 0.
            top=null; //top to null.
            this.stackSize=stackSize; //StackSize param set
        }
        /**
         * Pushes an element onto the stack.
         * @param element element to be pushed on stack.
         */
        public void push(T element)
        {
            LinearNode<T> node = new LinearNode<T>(element); //creates new LinearNode object.
            if(count==stackSize)
            {
                LinearNode<T> tempNode; //create obj ref null default
                tempNode=top;
    
                while(tempNode.getNext()!=null)
                {
                    tempNode=tempNode.getNext();
                }
                tempNode=null;
                count--;
                //stackSize=stackSize+1;
            }
            node.setNext(top);
            top=node;
            count++;
        }
        
       /**
        *Peek at the top element on the stack. 
        *@return element element on the stack.
        */
        public T peek()
        {
            return top.getElement();
        }
        
       /**
        * Checks if the stack is empty.
        * @return true if stack is empty. 
        */
        public boolean isEmpty()
        {
            return count<=0;
        }
    
       /**
        * Returns the size of the stack as an int.
        * @return count the var that counts elements.
        */
        public int size()
        {
            return count;
        }
    
       /**
        * Returns a string representation of the stack.
        * @return str string representing the stack elements.
        */
        public String toString()
        {
            String str ="";
            LinearNode<T> topTemp = top;
            while(topTemp!=null)
            {
                System.out.println(topTemp.getElement());
                topTemp = topTemp.getNext();
            }
            return str;
        }
    }
    
    /** 
     * LinearNode class represents a node for a linked list.
     */
    public class LinearNode<T>
    {
        private LinearNode<T> next; //next obj ref null default
        private T element; // element var
    
       /**
        * Constructor for LinearNode. Empty node.
        */
        public LinearNode() //creates an empty node
        {
            element=null; //set element to null 
            next=null; //set next to null
    
        }
    
       /** 
        * Constructor overloaded for LinearNode.
        * @param element for node to store.
        */
        public LinearNode(T element)
        {
            this.element=element;
            next=null;
    
        }
    
      /**
       * Getter method. Gets the objects next ref.
       * @return next the node's next reference pointer.
       */
        public LinearNode<T> getNext()
        {
            return next;
        }
    
       /** 
        * Setter method. Sets the next data for the node.
        *
        */
        public void setNext(LinearNode<T> node)
        {
            next=node;
        }
    
       /** 
        * Gets the element.
        * @return element.
        */
        public T getElement()
        {
            return element;
        }
    
       /**
        * Sets the element.
        */
        public void setElement(T element)
        {
            this.element=element;
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Main class, main method.
     */
    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            DropOutStack<Integer> stack = new DropOutStack<Integer>(5);
            stack.push(1);
            stack.push(2);
            stack.push(3);
            stack.push(4);
            stack.push(5);
            stack.push(6);
            System.out.println(stack);
        }
    }
    //End of classes. 
    
    ```
````

Comment: Please make a [MRE]

Answer (score 1):

You have to revisit the `push` method of your `DropOutStack`.

At this codepart

```java
LinearNode<T> tempNode; //create obj ref null default
tempNode=top;

while(tempNode.getNext()!=null)
{
    tempNode=tempNode.getNext();
}
```

you are iterating to the bottom of the stack and assign the object at the bottom of the stack to `tempNode`.

When setting `tempNode` to `null`, only `tempNode` is referring to null. The instance-variable `next` of the `LinearNode` next to the bottom is still referring to the bottom element.

Therefore, to achieve the bottom element to be "dropped", you have to find the next-to-bottom element and set `next` of this object to `null`.

To find the next-to-bottom element of the `DropOutStack` you can do something like this:

```java
while(tempNode.getNext()!=null && tempNode.getNext().getNext() != null)
{
    tempNode=tempNode.getNext();
}
```

(I have insterted the first condition of the `while` loop to prevent a `NullPointerException` in case the size of the stack is only 1)

After this, you have to set `next` of this element to `null`:

```
tempNode.setNext(null);
```

I hope this explanation helps you to understand what is happening in your code.

Finally, here is a working `push` method for your `DropOutStack`:

```java
  public void push(T element)
  {
    LinearNode<T> node = new LinearNode<T>(element); //creates new LinearNode object.
    if(count==stackSize)
    {
      LinearNode<T> tempNode; //create obj ref null default
      tempNode=top;

      while(tempNode.getNext()!=null && tempNode.getNext().getNext() != null)
      {
        tempNode=tempNode.getNext();
      }
      tempNode.setNext(null);
      count--;
    }
    node.setNext(top);
    top=node;
    count++;
  }
```

Comment: thanks, I'll have to debug to see how it's working now. does tempNode.getNext().getNext() just mean get the next for the next two elements?  Like if the stack was the same.                       1,2,3,4,5,6 then if it starts at 6 it would get the next of 5 and 4?Thanks

Comment: `tempNode.getNext()` delivers the the next `LinearNode`. The second `getNext` is called on the object delivered from the first call. (Maybe you've already heard about method chaining, if not, see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-chaining-in-java-with-examples/). Correct: If the top Element is six: 6->5->4->3->2->1->`null` and you call `tempNode.getNext().getNext()` on the node containing 6 it delivers the Element containing 4.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are making this much harder than necessary.  Here are a few suggestions.

- For your node class, make it a `private, inner class`. Inner classes are typically helper classes that are related in some way to the enclosing class.  So this is a perfect use for them.  It also allows you to use the type specifier `T` of the enclosing class without having to declare its own.  Using `getters` and `setters` is ok but not really necessary since this is a private class and you don't need to hide implementation details.
- When you are pushing a value onto the stack, there is no need to iterate over the stack if it has met its capacity. In fact, no iterations should be required anywhere except possibly in your `toString` method.  I would recommend two things:

  1. Don't update the count of items but still add one to the beginning for a push.
  2. maintain a `tail` node adjust this to point to the now next to last node. Set the reference to the last node to null for garbage collection.  This effectively `removes` an element and frees up a node.
- And probably most important is to design this on paper, showing nodes and forward (and backward if any) references.  It makes it easier to visualize how to modify the head and tail nodes and other ancillary fields.